# What is the difference between phrase and term in structured queries?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

How are `phrase` and `term` different in a `Structured` query?

I have this data in my CloudSearch domain:

```
{
    "guid": 9,
    "operating_systems": [
        "12345", "123"
    ],
    "manufacturer": "sealand",
    "model": "gaming tree whale plum",
    "identifier": "gaming tree whale plum",
    "type": "computer",
    "created_at": "1982-10-14T14:43:54Z"
}
```

`"model"` is type `text`, `"identifier"` is type `literal`, `"created_at"` is type `date`.

Let's make a few queries:

```
(phrase field=model 'tree whale')                match
(phrase field= identifier 'tree whale')          no match
(phrase 'tree whale')                            match
(phrase field=created_at '1982-10-14T14:43:54Z') match (this shouldn't match according to docs)

(term field=model 'tree whale')                match
(term field= identifier 'tree whale')          no match
(term 'tree whale')                            match
(term field=created_at '1982-10-14T14:43:54Z') match
```

Is there anything I can do with `phrase` that I can't do with `term` and vice-versa?

Comment: `phrase` matches exact order and `term` matches if the field contains the search term anywhere. "Sloppy phrases" are possible. Are you looking for any other specific differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is very little difference between the syntax and usage of `term` VS `phrase`. However, search behavior in handling `phrases` can be customized in ways `terms` cannot, which can be used to improve performance:

- allowed operators
- phraseFields
- phraseSlop

`Terms` are intended for matching text fields, where `phrases` are intended for more complex searches.

Skip the web documentation, and just read all of the PDF:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/cloudsearch-dg.pdf

Comment: When you say *phrases are intended for more complex searches* what do you mean? I would have thought that phrases are more strict and less flexible when it comes to searching, so overall you could do less complex things with them.

Comment: I can only guess, as with any architecture greater rigidity allows for better performance, as well as more flexibility of components which depend on it.  Ultimately, phrases become more flexible only when you consider the implications of aliases and equivalent terms. {citrus, lemon, orange} {large, big, huge} `(phrase "big lemon") would match all possible combinations.

Comment: with `term` it won't check each word, it will only check the whole.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is wondering, turns out that a phrase search matches the entire phrase while a term search matches the terms which may be a phrase but may be words spread around the document. Example:

Text:

```
"model": gaming tree whale plum
```

The following hold:

```
(phrase field=model 'tree whale')                match
(phrase field=model 'tree plum')                 no match

(term field=model 'tree whale')                  match
(term field=model 'tree plum')                   match
```